# Как записывать значения в таблицу каждый раз в первую строку, имеющие значения опускать на строку ниже Python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Есть данный код, который добавляет запись последовательно заполнению(последняя строчка), подскажите как можно реализовать заполнение, что бы записывалось в первую стр и данные которые уже есть опускались на строку вниз.

```
def records(self, name, attribute, old_size, new_size, compressed):
    self.db.insert_data(name, attribute, old_size, new_size, compressed)
    self.view_records()

def view_records(self):
    self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM DataImg''')
    [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
    [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row) for row in self.db.c.fetchall()]
```

Comment: В SQLite, как и в других СУБД, данные хранятся неупорядоченно. Без использования выражения `ORDER BY` в запросе, понятие "первая строка" не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте поле с автоинкрементом, например `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`. Вставляете данные без этого поля. Получаете данные через `select... order by id desc` и получите значения в порядке "последнее сверху".